# Assigning to a positional parameter

Tags: bash, positional-parameter

How can I assign a value to a positional parameter in Bash? I want to assign a value to a default parameter:

```
if [ -z "$4" ]; then
   4=$3
fi
```

Indicating that 4 is not a command.

Answer (score 39):

The `set` built-in is the only way to set positional parameters

```
$ set -- this is a test
$ echo $1
```

> ```
> this
> ```

```
$ echo $4
```

> ```
> test
> ```

where the `--` protects against things that look like options (e.g. `-x`).

In your case you might want:

```
if [ -z "$4" ]; then
   set -- "$1" "$2" "$3" "$3"
fi
```

but it would probably be more clear as

```
if [ -z "$4" ]; then
   # default the fourth option if it is null
   fourth="$3"
   set -- "$1" "$2" "$3" "$fourth"
fi
```

you might also want to look at the parameter count `$#` instead of testing for `-z`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do what you want by calling your script again with a fourth parameter:

```
if [ -z "$4" ]; then
   $0 "$1" "$2" "$3" "$3"
   exit $?
fi
echo $4
```

Calling above script like `./script.sh one two three` will output:

> three

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with an assignment directly into an auxiliary array with an export/import type mechanism:

```
set a b c "d e f" g h    
thisArray=( "$@" )
thisArray[3]=4
set -- "${thisArray[@]}"
echo "$@"
```

outputs 'a b c 4 g h'