# What shell command splits words into variables?

Tags: shell

There is a command that will split words in variables so the end up in

```
$1, $2, $3...
```

Totally forgot begins with S for some reason think its `set` but the grey matter is not working.

What I am doing is I have a `fstab` like file that each line represents certain commands separated by tab.
Each line can have a different number of columns and without defining variables there is a command that splits to `$1, $2...` but can I remember and google isn't working for me today either.

Comment: Do you mean `set`? Like `set -- $var`

Comment: What do you want to do with those variables?

Comment: It is set isn't it dunno why my googling failed but yes 'set $var' think I should go back to bed.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assigning to a positional parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762370/assigning-to-a-positional-parameter)

Comment: Yeah delete as did go back to bed :)

Many Thanks