# How to replace each delimiter in an arbitrary number of command-line arguments that are all delimited name-value pairs?

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion, positional-parameter

[How to change a command line argument in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827690/how-to-change-a-command-line-argument-in-bash) explains how to modify input arguments in bash.

But in my case, I have a dynamic set of input arguments. I don't know how many are there.

This is my command:

```
send url key1=value1 key2=value2 key3=value3
```

I want to change all of the `=` signs to `:` automatically. And the `key=value` pairs are not limited.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
set -- "${@/=/:}"
```

This replaces, in every positional parameter, the first equals sign with a colon.

See [Assigning to a positional parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762370/assigning-to-a-positional-parameter) for further information on the `set` command.